# Texture quality cut when tested on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, textures

I am running into problems with my enemy textures when I build and APK and test the game on an android. The pixel quantity drops to 25% of what it used to be. I have tried changing some of the quality settings, etc, but i can't seem to find the source of the problem.

I am running Unity 4.6.0f3 on a Windows 8.1 Asus. I am running the APK on Bluestacks on said computer.
I am not the only person who is seeing the lack of pixels.

Unity:
[image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8rc2rKH9297NjNsVUhLWnppckE]

Bluestacks:
[image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8rc2rKH9297eXVVQmtMMFBXNEk]

Comment: Have you tried other emulators/real devices - Genymotion, Intel HAXM, various Android devices to see if its consistent in some way?

Comment: Every single person who tested this APK has received this error. The problem comes from the APK building, not from the device running the APK. I have other projects with VERY similar code that build and run fine, this is the only one that doesn't.

Comment: You probably checked, but make sure your quality settings on the Android platform don't select lower quality textures. Check Edit > Project Settings > Quality and make sure Texture Quality is not set to Half Res or Quarter Res. (BTW, the images in your question are not displaying properly.)

Comment: Looks like the image links work if I remove "&authuser=0" from the URL. But you put the same image URL twice.

Comment: The Texture Quality is at Full Resolution.

Comment: @yoyo you have any other ideas that might work?

Comment: Sorry, that's all I got. Good luck.

Comment: From the images it seems to affect all the textures, e.g. the orange bottom part looks way more blurry on the second image. Maybe you can provide more information about what exactly you tried, or what your texture settings  (overrides for android?) look like.

Comment: The textures are blurry from small file size. That part is normal. The enemy Textures are intentionally much higher resolutions to avoid this. But even if we didn't the enemies would just look blurred, not like they where just 16 pixels per face. For some reason this only affects the enemies' textures.

Comment: The only difference between the enemy textures and the others is that it uses a Skinned Mesh Renderer, while the other textures use Mesh Renderers.